# Checking the invertibility of a function

Tags: functions

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3,\dots,100\}$ and $\mathscr{P}(X)$ denote the power set of $X$. Consider the function $d : \mathscr{P}(X)\rightarrow\mathscr{P}(X)$ defined by $d(A) = A\Delta\{1\}$ where $\Delta$ denotes the symmetric difference. Is this function injective, surjective or bijective? If the function is invertible, find its inverse.

Comment: What have you tried?  How about doing it by hand for $X=\{1,2\}$?  All the elements except $1$ are equivalent.

Comment: The things is i am new to the concent of sets being functions so i am having issues doing such questions. I understand the fundamentals i.e. the definitions of injective, surjective and bijective and their connection to counting i.e. the size of domain and co-domian. but what i dont know is how to apply to functions which has powersets and etc. But lets try the simple examples you gave. So ()={{}, {1},{2},{1,2}}. now my understanding is that A ⊆ X. so A can have values from 1, 2. or is A⊆()?

Comment: The function is defined from subsets of $X$ to subsets of $X$, so $A$ needs to be a subset of $X$.  It can be any of the elements of $P(X)$, which you listed.  You should be able to find $f(A)$ for each of those four subsets.

Comment: so A can be any of {{}, {1},{2},{1,2}}. so f({})= {}Δ{1}= {1} and f({1})={1}Δ{1}={}and f({2})={2}Δ{1} = {2,1}={1,2} and f({1,2})={1,2}Δ{1} = {2}. hence d(A)=A. ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now, is it surjective and injective?

Comment: It is surjective as the co-domian is the range and injective as all possible pre-imagine have unique imagine in the co-domain. implying d(A) is bijective. But now how do i find the inverse? thanks for this much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that is correct,so it is bijective.  Note that $d$ adds $1$ into a set if it is not there and removes it if it is there, like negation.  Like negation, it is its own inverse.  In all cases $d(d(A))=A$  I suggest you write up all of this as an answer.  The FAQ encourages that.  It will help you see if you really understand it.  After a delay, you will be allowed to accept it.

Comment: what do you mean like negation it is its own inverse? and how is d(d(A))= A because for me d(d(A))=d(AΔ{1})

Comment: Negation is its own inverse because if $f(x)=-x, f(f(x))=f(-x)=x$.  Similarly here, $d(d(A))=d(A\triangle 1)=(A\triangle 1)\triangle 1=A$  The first triangle changes whether $1$ is in the set and the second changes it back.

Comment: yes i get it now thanks for this much appreciated.

Comment: sorry but how would i put this all in a proof format.